# matplotlib can not make good plot even series are sorted

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make fit to data with a function using `kmpfit`. I wrote a function and create the data which I need. But I couldn't make fit I do not know why. For diagnose the problem I wrote a little code including the function and data manually.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, deg2rad, cos, sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0.0227 
b = 0.62
c = 8
c = deg2rad(c)
nuv = [-3.1100378489321852, -3.080779513591613, -2.9623116962718488,
       -2.9320051771903497, -2.9013199203020847, -2.8701927054527872,
       -2.8385560698050005, -2.8064753639671229, -2.7735993901156806,
       0.36844509142666976, -1.9705142582292372, -1.9480811770908353,
       -1.8947986536539931, -1.7815887886073671, -1.6265828144867829,
       -1.4715907393121233, -1.3596977825555951, -1.1806587672501143,
       -0.55288603288541771, -0.3438991564882124, -0.096758921190596897,
       0.1421861377303521, 0.1521340052085457, 0.17640752287484385,
       0.18191492261884601, 0.40234958689656314, 0.40867327724685887,
       0.63794208658968032, 0.81961004137343407, 1.05736971066194,
       -1.70274820249535, -1.70274820249535, 0.42810230167965252,
       1.0554491959743697, 2.7430022419118756, 2.8118425268507146,
       -3.0820210311891394, -3.0820210311891394, -3.0806553516084221,
       -3.079537808956486, -3.051416931311882, -3.0491716855327584,
       -3.0208948970571354, -2.9952067470859789, -2.9586059581956659,
       -2.8652681815246064, -2.2321198257675805, -2.2206413194692436,
       -2.0487466547184545, -1.8050857172004837, -1.7930212308038123,
       -1.7815887886073671, -1.7226178324645978, -1.4606334503318792,
       -0.83202979435506985, -1.7151892997754807, -0.83202979435506985,
       2.2102292057472126, 2.5763645851209516, 2.6016705429837792,
       2.6019932968419615, 2.6417842665684885, 2.7754289398605785,
       2.8800044863276719, 2.9639713200505731, 2.9665227207320721,
       3.0286694241613157, 3.035679936973573, -2.9347163938922485,
       -1.9155430346178968, -0.8329136783770752, -0.41183105265094888,
       -0.41183105265094888, -0.35565635716173022, -0.33425595343332393,
       -0.14550316836124572, -0.046748486226005727, -0.014472947078634411,
       0.010019854021946903, 0.15765630643413217, 0.16207184620306636,
       0.16979394098215997, 0.2455050636785748, 0.32888961322616905,
       0.34068709407632647, 0.41393471786055941, 0.81604599160336466,
       0.82227854519908261, 0.82405538828268077, 0.88429703962531769,
       0.8920027798874578, 0.8937104108565872, 1.0380482588180733,
       1.0550647837167857, 1.0673149179289214, 1.0892511472554207,
       1.090751378101996, 1.1019515646556739, 1.2159122481551932,
       1.3542493616501501, 1.5210878230651259, 1.6218954762172026,
       1.7141232570434284, 1.7217718347292865, 1.7226178324645969,
       1.7264153759365395, 1.7272571820448859, 1.7272571820448859,
       1.7301975380711199, 1.7310359400385833, 1.7347994417661872,
       1.7356337138705407, 1.806630835761261, 1.8093284840635859,
       1.8135515086252094, 1.8204197395679962, 1.8238344030699196,
       1.8287440216294626, 1.8294969830398455, 1.8321274088390307,
       1.8362454868831941, 1.8396008708675498, 1.9100585907395602,
       1.9107460107483889, 1.9131477787112994, 1.9260731388299077,
       1.9328005884380208, 1.9775475878862827, 1.9804086181362759,
       1.9832603038017205, 1.9838927484750857, 1.9901921074027069,
       1.9958228822074535, 1.996446284121739, 2.0054358275605568,
       2.0075918811971802, 2.0115818619978514, 2.3438068328193378,
       2.3475719712881635, 2.5352777696149347, 2.6364743870415346,
       2.6367874035598713, 2.6441192165852141, 2.6787571357364954,
       2.6787571357364954, 2.7127462059565524, 2.8155478976210593,
       2.8155478976210593, 2.9637160558930811, 2.9688170723543408,
       2.971618862419588059, 2.971618862419588059, 2.971873440211980633,
        2.973909288536141116, 2.973909288536141116, 2.973909288536141116,
        2.973909288536141116, 2.975053852915546138, 2.988756120609725730,
        2.988756120609725730, 2.997733101268694078, 3.002528215246087484,
        3.024533112572501015, 3.029546326593630212, 3.029796838704217787,
        3.029796838704217787, 3.057773628487484352, 3.057773628487484352,
        3.082021031189138949, 3.082269312603408196, 3.082269312603408196,
        3.090830763730009867, 3.090830763730009867, 3.117465833634534444,
        3.117713382754725870, 3.118579781836214870, -3.137757833066940893,
        -3.135283702532828620, -3.116475607291006700, -3.111771326539556348,
        -3.110409324019566490, -3.107684967030220680, -3.085124032183865328,
        -3.080655351608422077, -3.080655351608422077, -3.056153954170345965,
        -3.056153954170345965, -3.055032380304064876, -3.051416931311881964,
        -3.050294422847536602, -3.046426235155258233, -3.045052977567606955,
        -3.040306178547460547, -3.025410839089959669, -3.023153466326280903,
        -3.019514061115116110, -3.019514061115116110, -3.019262950653463840,
        -3.016499720202928891, -2.999752879791346860, -2.998616895900385160,
        -2.994448482862606120, -2.991034216204778495, -2.991034216204778495,
        -2.990528106552184262, -2.989642231047596077, -2.989642231047596077,
        -2.989389080673096721, -2.958605958195665853, -2.958605958195665853,
        -2.957199051665845069, -2.956047415437953241, -2.937037941583197309,
        -2.936135373597172027, -2.936135373597172027, -2.933554808031611394,
        -2.928385552843677075, -2.925796788473665533, -2.925796788473665533,
        -2.925796788473665533, -2.922038082369069034, -2.902759480161329453,
        -2.898962204439052393, -2.898962204439052393, -2.896339471914807007,
        -2.896077020722079620, -2.895158185244958382, -2.882119579422069311,
        -2.875900099747880301, -2.871787148454901129, -2.870059775925943413,
        -2.869129012901771691, -2.867931656264596008, -2.867931656264596008,
        -2.866467204747387143, -2.863801681292100110, -2.849610622824613859,
        -2.845708912151509562, -2.841798674778476475, -2.841528685437748170,
        -2.840718469700393545, -2.839502447218564818, -2.837609180862810554,
        -2.837609180862810554, -2.836526393188437023, -2.836526393188437023,
        -2.836526393188437023, -2.833680862943071865, -2.830966469768766647,
        -2.829743591062164665, -2.825524720994100569, -2.805923873667341972,
        -2.805923873667341972, -2.799983281140289826, -2.772472390997511305,
        -2.768379789942246649, -2.766824435443637320, -2.764275729560100370,
        -2.762999699224984340, -2.745014796094586540, -2.744152629090993667,
        -2.737380381285281494, -2.733474818276803830, -2.730574582701303932,
        -2.717445680460369939, -2.701665112039076000, -2.700774510031100917,
        -2.698694031318560338, -2.675428407219024862, -2.674064059032170704,
        -2.670114064245184160, -2.668439062508604298, -2.640381059271863062,
        -2.636630905835811056, -2.634751286742769150, -2.634751286742769150,
        -2.633025622057135084, -2.603122198063127168, -2.593733550579019553,
        -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092,
        -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092,
        -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092,
        -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092,
        -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092, -2.591943900609491092,
        -2.591943900609491092, -2.557198935840220955, -2.556357760724297989,
        -2.556357760724297989, -2.554504812183617801, -2.551465665960842788,
        -2.551465665960842788, -2.551465665960842788, -2.557198935840220955,
        -2.516036394815908128, -2.516036394815908128, -2.514109693073277363,
        -2.514109693073277363, -2.514109693073277363, -2.503889574820031161,
        -2.466719975263720777, -2.466719975263720777, -2.432279951567988707,
        -2.430181354620980727, -2.428078119158226134, -2.428078119158226134,
        -2.428078119158226134, -2.428078119158226134, -2.428078119158226134,
        -2.428078119158226134, -2.424242083499746236, -2.424242083499746236,
        -2.381583470295975502, -2.335383578464432563, -2.335383578464432563,
        -2.335383578464432563, -2.335383578464432563, -2.335383578464432563,
        -2.335383578464432563, -2.335383578464432563, -2.335383578464432563,
        -2.335383578464432563, -2.333053400737972183, -2.329227393977091332,
        -2.281773812575356608, -2.279750200242793845, -2.279750200242793845,
        -2.234729303035567938, -2.232119825767580501, -2.229502570044278098,
        -2.228071679356622870, -2.173412272402481804, -2.170612733225716795,
        -2.164216418661920383, -2.104148289132928618, -2.101667801314274442,
        -2.101667801314274442, -2.101667801314274442, -2.101667801314274442,
        -2.101667801314274442, -2.101667801314274442, -2.051967952719272237,
        -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679,
        -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679,
        -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679,
        -2.042858917550592679, -2.042858917550592679, -2.036930947914699530,
        -2.036930947914699530, -2.036930947914699530, -2.036930947914699530,
        -2.036335917577979160, -2.036335917577979160, -2.036335917577979160,
        -2.034250093056099828, -1.981994037929359465, -1.970514258229237203,
        -1.970514258229237203, -1.970514258229237203, -1.970514258229237203,
        -1.964070851165442777, -1.964070851165442777, -1.964070851165442777,
        -1.964070851165442777, -1.964070851165442777, -1.964070851165442777,
        -1.964070851165442777, -1.964070851165442777, -1.964070851165442777,
        -1.880694393422799982, -1.816992136425608750, -1.800823048868167131,
        -1.692108066074450079, -1.596670759700378639, -1.596670759700378639,
        -1.493168944954045729, -1.455665479743565971, -1.359697782555595147,
        -1.215912248155192499, -1.027898534189456425, -1.325676609134822881]
epoch = [0., 236., 1179., 1415., 1651., 1887., 2123., 2358.,
        2594., 9856., 6603., 6672., 6829., 7133., 7493.,
        7800., 7995., 8270., 9006., 9207., 9433., 9648.,
        9657., 9679., 9684., 9888., 9894., 10120., 10315.,
        10602., 7323.5, 7323.5, 9912.5, 10599.5, -3319., -2829.,
        226., 226., 237., 246., 472., 490., 716., 920.,
        1208., 1924., 5652., 5700., 6348., 7073., 7104.,
        7133., 7277., 7820., 8711., 7294.5, 8711., -6253.,
        -4404., -4249., -4247., -3996., -3091., -2323.,
        -1676., -1656., -1164., -1108., 1394., -12781.,
        -10840., -10407., -10407., -10354., -10334.,
        -10161., -10072., -10043., -10021., -9888.,
        -9884., -9877., -9808., -9731., -9720., -9651.,
        -9239., -9232., -9230., -9161., -9152., -9150.,
        -8973., -8951., -8935., -8906., -8904., -8889.,
        -8729., -8514., -8217., -8013., -7807., -7789.,
        -7787., -7778., -7776., -7776., -7769., -7767.,
        -7758., -7756., -7579., -7572., -7561., -7543.,
        -7534., -7521., -7519., -7512., -7501., -7492.,
        -7295., -7293., -7286., -7248., -7228., -7091.,
        -7082., -7073., -7071., -7051., -7033., -7031.,
        -7002., -6995., -6982., -5661., -5643., -4648.,
        -4030., -4028., -3981., -3755., -3755., -3527.,
        -2802., -2802., -1678., -1638., -1616., -1616.,
        -1614., -1598., -1598., -1598., -1598., -1589.,
        -1481., -1481., -1410., -1372., -1197., -1157.,
        -1155., -1155., -931., -931., -736., -734., -734.,
        -665., -665., -450., -448., -441., -224., -204.,
        -52., -14., -3., 19., 201., 237., 237., 434.,
        434., 443., 472., 481., 512., 523., 561., 680.,
        698., 727., 727., 729., 751., 884., 893., 926.,
        953., 953., 957., 964., 964., 966., 1208., 1208.,
        1219., 1228., 1376., 1383., 1383., 1403., 1443.,
        1463., 1463., 1463., 1492., 1640., 1669.,
        1669., 1689., 1691., 1698., 1797., 1844.,
        1875., 1888., 1895., 1904., 1904., 1915.,
        1935., 2041., 2070., 2099., 2101., 2107.,
        2116., 2130., 2130., 2138., 2138., 2138.,
        2159., 2179., 2188., 2219., 2362., 2362.,
        2405., 2602., 2631., 2642., 2660., 2669.,
        2795., 2801., 2848., 2875., 2895., 2985.,
        3092., 3098., 3112., 3267., 3276., 3302.,
        3313., 3495., 3519., 3531., 3531., 3542.,
        3730., 3788., 3799., 3799., 3799., 3799.,
        3799., 3799., 3799., 3799., 3799., 3799.,
        3799., 3799., 3799., 3799., 3799., 3799.,
        4009., 4014., 4014., 4025., 4043., 4043.,
        4043., 4009., 4249., 4249., 4260., 4260.,
        4260., 4318., 4524., 4524., 4708., 4719.,
        4730., 4730., 4730., 4730., 4730., 4730.,
        4750., 4750., 4967., 5191., 5191., 5191.,
        5191., 5191., 5191., 5191., 5191., 5191.,
        5202., 5220., 5437., 5446., 5446., 5641.,
        5652., 5663., 5669., 5891., 5902., 5927.,
        6153., 6162., 6162., 6162., 6162., 6162.,
        6162., 6337., 6368., 6368., 6368., 6368.,
        6368., 6368., 6368., 6368., 6368., 6368.,
        6368., 6388., 6388., 6388., 6388., 6390.,
        6390., 6390., 6397., 6567., 6603., 6603.,
        6603., 6603., 6623., 6623., 6623., 6623.,
        6623., 6623., 6623., 6623., 6623., 6869.,
        7042., 7084., 7348., 7556., 7556., 7760.,
        7829., 7995., 8219., 8476., 8050.5]

sonuc = []
del sonuc[:]

for i in range(len(nuv)):
    y = a/sqrt(1 - b**2*cos(c)**2) *\
        (1 - b**2)/(1 + b*cos(nuv[i])) *\
        (sin(nuv[i] + c) + b*sin(c))
    sonuc.append(y)

xmin = min(epoch)
xmax = max(epoch)
xlen = len(epoch)
fitx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xlen)

plt.plot(fitx, sonuc, "r-")
plt.plot(epoch, sonuc, "r*")
plt.show()
```

As a result I compare both plot as below, stars are represent `epoch` vs `sonuc` and red line is `fit` vs `sonuc`

[image]

I guess I tried every alternative probabilities. I sorted `x` and `y` axes. I changed positions. But result is same. And when I tried to plot epoch and `sonuc`with continuous line, stars in chart1 changing like this;
[I tried both way sorted and not. It's not changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shjek.png)
I couldn't find where the problem is.

Comment: why did you include the [r] tag for your question?

Comment: System suggest r tag and I think that could be useful because most r users know python and matplotlib too. Thanks for edit suggestion I approved that.

Comment: I don't think that your problem is the plotting, but understanding what the fit does.

Comment: I did not use fit here. I just use the function. In theory that function gives a sinusoidal change. I am calculating manually results here so i did not use the kmpfit functions

Comment: I never said you use a fit here. I am saying that you probably don't understand it. What are your two variables (dependent and independent)? What is the resulting equation for the fitting process?

Comment: Equation is complex a kittle bit. It has 4 variable 3 of them is independent (a, b, c) and last one (nuv) is dependent. The process of finding ''nuv'' irrevelant with the equation. Weird thing is plot with stars gives correct sinusoidal result. But i can not plot it with line.

Comment: Well, your `sonuc`-`epoch` pairs correspond to each other, but they are not sorted with respect to `x` component. You have to sort the `y` data to have increasing `x`. And you need to interpolate the `y` data for your `fitx` points. Or maybe I'm missing your problem entirely... It's as if you were plotting `sonuc` vs `sort(epoch)`...

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you b your suggestion I made these changes:
...
epoch, sonuc = zip(*sorted(zip(epoch, sonuc)))
plt.plot(epoch,sonuc,"r-")
It is working now. Thanks a lot!